# Creating executable file with password included in a script

Tags: icons, sudo, gnome-terminal, ppp

How can I execute a `sudo` command by double clicking an icon ( password should be part of the script). Please help! Excuse if question is a blunder. My gnome-ppp is not detecting my BSNL modem when I run w/o `sudo` command. I would like to make a executable file for the `sudo` command `sudo gnome-ppp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the password (which is completely insecure, and breaks if you ever change it), you should edit the sudoers file and allow `sudo gnome-ppp` to be run without a password:

First, check if you're in the `adm` user group:

```
groups
```

This should give you a list of your groups; I chose `adm`, because that includes users who can administer the system. It may be `admin` in your case; adjust accordingly.

Now find where `gnome-ppp` lives:

```
which gnome-ppp
```

This will give you the full path; in my case, it's `/usr/bin/gnome-ppp`

```
sudo visudo
```

and add the line at the bottom:

```
%adm ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/gnome-ppp
```

Save the file; now when you call `sudo gnome-ppp`, you will not be prompted for a password.

Comment: I was able to open visudo. What should i do type "%adm ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/gnome-ppp" at bottom of the terminal screen. (How to save and exit)

Comment: Depends on your editor - in `vim`, it's `:wq`, in `nano`, it's `Ctrl+X Y Enter`

Comment: Mine was nano. And ctr X worked. it was displayed as ^X. I never realized that ^ meant CTRL. Now its working fine.

Comment: Wonderful. Glad it helped. (`^` for `Control` is an ancient and widespread custom; note that e.g. pressing `Ctrl+C` shows `^C` in terminal)